# Reg: SSL Certificate Changes

Tags: excel, ssl

We have recently changed out SSL certificates on our application and there are some external tools that connect to our application like excels, my question:

1. Do we need to make any changes to excel to make sure that their connection properties are updated automatically with new ssl certificates details or will it connect directly without any changes needed on our end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have problems if you are using a self signed certificate. If not, I do not think you will need to update your excel.

Answer (score 2):

Basically installing SSL certificates on your application will secure incoming and outgoing information from that application w/c don't require any changes coming from any incoming 3rd party sources. So, no there is no need to change anything on your excel.